# tomcat unique context for each subdomain

Tags: tomcat, subdomain, unique, config, contextpath

I actually developed a j2ee webapp.

This webapp contains several subdomains (ar.app.ma, en.app.ma, app.ma ...).

I realized that deployment, each subdomain has its own context, therefore, its own objects, different from those of other subdomains)

This has the consequence of unpleasant phenomenons. For example, a user who logs on www.app.ma is not automatically connected to ar.app.ma).
The connection pool that is in the session is instantiated as many times as there are subdomains configured.

You would know a way to modify the config subdomain (or context of each of the webapp) so that all subdomains have the same unique context?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for single sign-on. Tomcat supports that.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution on tomcat official website.

In Tomcat, the host names and web apps are bound in a many-to-many relationship. There will be one host entry for each host. 
When multiple host names are bound to the same web app, one can use Tomcat's aliases facility.

```
<Host name="www.mycompany.com" ...>
  <Alias>mycompany.com</Alias>
  <Alias>en.mycompany.com</Alias>
  <Alias>fr.mycompany.com</Alias>
```

Comment: You can "accept" our own answer by clicking on the green tick. This removes the question from the pool of unsolved problems on StackOverflow.